# Nested fractional denominator(up to infinity)calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics, fractions, irrational-numbers

**Question:**

$$4 + \dfrac{1}{2 + \dfrac{1}{1 + \dfrac{1}{3 + \dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{2 + \dfrac{1}{8 + \dfrac{1}{\ddots}}}}}}} = \sqrt{A}$$

Find the positive integer $A$ in the equation above.

**Details and assumptions**

- The pattern repeats 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 8 infinitely, but 4 comes only once, i.e., at the beginning.

**My Approach:**

*I was thinking whether I should calculate each fractional part of the denominators or is there any other shorter method to solve this problem.*

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could edit your post to include the main content as [MathJax formatted text](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) rather than as an image.  Images don't get along well with either search engines or screenreaders.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "calculate each fractional part.."

Comment: I meant the denominators  by terming "calculate each fractional part"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a simpler example first: say, $$\sqrt{A}=1+{2\over 3+{2\over 3+...}}.$$ Here the repetition $2,3,2,3, ...$ continues forever after the $1$.

The problem is that this looks on the face of it like some sort of "infinitary" equation (or rather, it's a normal equation with an "infinitary" *term* in it). We want to somehow "tame" the right-hand side.

This is where the *repetition*, or *self-similarity*, comes in. Let $x={2\over 3+{2\over 3+...}}$. Then if we take the reciprocal of both sides, we see something interesting: $${1\over x}={3+x\over 2}.$$ Solving for $x$ yields $$x^2+3x-2=0,$$ which has as its solutions $$-3\pm\sqrt{9+8}\over 2,$$ that is, $$x={\sqrt{17}-3\over 2}\quad\mbox{or}\quad x={-\sqrt{17}-3\over 2}.$$ Since $x$ is clearly positive$^*$, it has to be the former.

Plugging back into the original expression, we have $$\sqrt{A}=1+x={\sqrt{17}-1\over 2}.$$ Squaring both sides finishes the problem.

Can you see how to follow a similar argument here? *(It's definitely going to be messier since your patter takes longer to repeat, but the basic idea still applies.)*

An interesting feature of this argument is: *it totally breaks down if we don't have repetition*! To see what I mean, try to calculate $$1\over 2+{3\over 4+{5\over 6+...}}.$$ In general, things are much more complicated and the "naive" argument above simply doesn't work.

---

There is a subtlety here; namely, that we haven't really *defined* what an "infinitary" fraction (called a ["continued fraction"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions_and_convergents)) like this actually *is*. But it should be clear that any reasonable definition will yield a positive answer here, since no piece involved is negative.

Comment: Can I post my solution so that you can review it once .